# updating a list on VueJS by using the real-time change-listener on firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a table with students list rendering by v-for loop from the backend. each cell is an input so I can edit it, though I want the changes to apear in real time for all of the users.
but something in my code isn't working. If I open it in another tab, I still have to refresh to see the changes. in the console it looks like the changes are recieved on the new tab too.
here is my code:

```
db.collection('students')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change=>{
          let doc = change.doc
          console.log('changed!');
          console.log(doc.data());
          let editedStudent = doc.data()
          let oldStudent = this.studentsList.filter(student=>{
            return student.studentID==editedStudent.studentID
          })
          oldStudent = oldStudent[0]
          console.log(editedStudent);
          console.log(oldStudent.firstName);
          console.log(doc.id);
          console.log(oldStudent);
          console.log(this.studentsList.indexOf(oldStudent));
          this.studentsList[this.studentsList.indexOf(oldStudent)]=editedStudent

          })
```

Comment: Could you update your post with the relative part in your template? I think you're using the wrong `key` in your `v-for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical Vue reactivity issue, you should use `this.$set` on the last line

```
db.collection('students')
  .onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change=>{
      let doc = change.doc
      console.log('changed!');
      let editedStudent = doc.data()
      console.log(editedStudent);
      let ioldStudent = this.studentsList.findIndex(student=> student.studentID==editedStudent.studentID)
      this.$set(studentsList, ioldStudent , editedStudent)
    })
  })
```

More info [bullet 1 here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

Comment: `$set` should be last resort imo. I think the change is not detected because of OP using the wrong key in their `v-for`.

Comment: Check my link, reactivity does not work if you set an array element by index

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, apologies. However, `splice` would accomplish the same and looks less "hacky" in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects), you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), to fill your old object with new data without losing reactivity.

```js
db.collection('students')
  .onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change=>{
      let doc = change.doc
      let editedStudent = doc.data()

      let oldStudent = this.studentsList.find(student => 
        student.studentID === editedStudent.studentID
      )
      Object.assign(oldStudent, editedStudent)
    })
  })
```